# Tidyverse version of nested for loops

Tags: r, purrr, xtable

I am wondering if there is a tidyverse implementation of the nested for loop. I am trying to "walk" along the elements of two nested lists and print out formatted tables.

```
library(xtable)

for (i in 1:9) {
  for (j in 1:7) {
    result <- tab_male[[i]][[j]]
    cat(result$form, result$num, sep = "\n")
    result_f <- xtable(result$table, digits = c(0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0))
    print(result_f, type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Data:

```
> list(list(list(form = "ISL_cor ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile +
> AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos", 
>     num = "n = 243, v = 694", table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(-0.0791579099605819, 
>     -1.31886212979935, -1.48893696108341, NA), std.error = c(0.401568948969462, 
>     0.473022615063467, 0.530936266824937, NA), statistic = c(0.0388569214847496, 
>     7.77382905796715, 7.86444062797599, 13.2403535895265), p.value = c(0.843732388037004, 
>     0.00530085657147317, 0.00504164207971813, 0.00414463354304205
>     ), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = "ISL_cor ~ AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + Visit_age + AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos", 
>     num = "n = 243, v = 691", table = structure(list(term = c("AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(-0.89154000871825, 
>     -0.994316436351536, -1.57011199247759, NA), std.error = c(0.702047826647497, 
>     0.661044419168572, 0.735530040163908, NA), statistic = c(1.61268028305808, 
>     2.26249668129015, 4.55680487390649, 4.65540410577618), p.value = c(0.204115445829441, 
>     0.13254022774479, 0.0327881883499254, 0.198840443392366), 
>         DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("ISL_cor ~ MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos + ",  "   
> SchoolYears"), num = "n = 243, v = 694", table = structure(list(
>     term = c("MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"), estimate = c(-0.330107428454537, 
>     -1.11363290045085, NA), std.error = c(0.421259777743314, 
>     0.584132185200777, NA), statistic = c(0.614059714422183, 
>     3.63464361400689, 3.74972860573148), p.value = c(0.433263337741689, 
>     0.0565887187958448, 0.153375778086435), DF = c(NA, NA, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
> -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("ISL_cor ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile +
> ",  "    Visit_age + AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos"), num = "n = 242, v =
> 690", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(-0.0479970904647452, 
>     -1.12670431496527, -1.21854957357748, -0.700531880187201, 
>     -0.49732099940717, -1.03791500617207, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.420765861836252, 
>     0.530854303316158, 0.608326118209642, 0.701020625547379, 
>     0.699785302029764, 0.77990402300362, NA, NA), statistic = c(0.0130121430708719, 
>     4.50473482079907, 4.01248551738978, 0.99860610382089, 0.50506114901101, 
>     1.77109256901535, 7.77644180358569, 1.97339725616004), p.value = c(0.909181684413754, 
>     0.033801136898189, 0.045164522721187, 0.317648025163335, 
>     0.477284698622016, 0.183246922804758, 0.0508651484245062, 
>     0.577946522968363), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
>     -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("ISL_cor ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile +
> MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + ",  "    AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos +
> SchoolYears"), num = "n = 243, v = 694", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"
>     ), estimate = c(-0.0437266901073021, -1.02439627611215, -1.01609109823191, 
>     -0.167581634650727, -0.691121853494014, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.408524542630128, 
>     0.473755244140277, 0.586929872792396, 0.426960923639793, 
>     0.633883630020921, NA, NA), statistic = c(0.0114566304473933, 
>     4.6754984937607, 2.99704224605943, 0.154055279458038, 1.18874903889876, 
>     6.89149629148188, 1.19563579590938), p.value = c(0.914760697307542, 
>     0.0305958220319473, 0.0834166758023506, 0.694689724690443, 
>     0.275582035248557, 0.0754377535413996, 0.550010506640863), 
>         DF = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
>     -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("ISL_cor ~ AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile +
> MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + ",  "    Visit_age +
> AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos"), num = "n = 242, v = 690", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"
>     ), estimate = c(-0.895040230761059, -0.912702903399016, -1.37975890875964, 
>     -0.489641166512556, -0.988393112135669, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.694777627862569, 
>     0.661366030220224, 0.729574978477178, 0.41719736053471, 0.576184797609155, 
>     NA, NA), statistic = c(1.65956192470069, 1.90447420695097, 
>     3.57656853703012, 1.37744016843595, 2.94263116126483, 3.74480686353552, 
>     3.6683597648995), p.value = c(0.197662482281952, 0.167578366779483, 
>     0.0586000822386175, 0.240537661418808, 0.0862700996563112, 
>     0.290371619583202, 0.159744457294298), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 
>     NA, NA, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("ISL_cor ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + ",  "   
> MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + Visit_age +
> AHQ_Out_Games_MainPos" ), num = "n = 242, v = 690", table =
> structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
> "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53",
> "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861",
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+",
> "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", 
> "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category" ),
> estimate = c(0.027473221623339, -0.983296707817596,
> -0.998915061769465, 
> -0.729302185929289, -0.516076193503656, -0.988004708036804, -0.326646742422211, 
> -0.65317896922332, NA, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.428839704885747, 
> 0.543671182971852, 0.642027892677446, 0.703866716093322, 0.699712682087769, 
> 0.772736325651738, 0.425575113535084, 0.608192913919347, NA,  NA, NA), statistic = c(0.00410420648439035, 3.27112049517389, 
> 2.42074660001576, 1.07357940675207, 0.543986547969826, 1.63476515114772, 
> 0.589120608607216, 1.15340458748084, 6.043351999308, 1.86319524453419, 
> 1.42191994516063), p.value = c(0.948919202216804, 0.0705094492798756, 
> 0.11973785101195, 0.300138340000943, 0.460785251427891, 0.20104522602314, 
> 0.44275937551614, 0.282837582724352, 0.109520000259034, 0.601280426978633, 
> 0.491172458976363), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3,  3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" )))),
> list(list(form = "GMCT_mps ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + Visit_age +
> AlcWeek_Category", 
>     num = "n = 237, v = 675", table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(0.0395760177476687, 
>     -0.0578397419137515, -0.170261152714884, NA), std.error = c(0.0397676090470122, 
>     0.0452542398137336, 0.0525940258932902, NA), statistic = c(0.990387665627256, 
>     1.63355644310893, 10.4799281952162, 17.8660680040739), p.value = c(0.319647644086372, 
>     0.201211847352926, 0.00120678446475631, 0.000468728794495572
>     ), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = "GMCT_mps ~ AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category", 
>     num = "n = 237, v = 672", table = structure(list(term = c("AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(0.0782736360902089, 
>     -0.048972529752338, -0.054639060767593, NA), std.error = c(0.0597872145397393, 
>     0.0604457000742019, 0.0554338598664709, NA), statistic = c(1.71401404789434, 
>     0.656408586949, 0.971529990187134, 5.75002358193762), p.value = c(0.190465395485205, 
>     0.417830717685593, 0.324298899988633, 0.124426125086254), 
>         DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = "GMCT_mps ~ MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category", 
>     num = "n = 237, v = 675", table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"
>     ), estimate = c(-0.0924725285404226, -0.138136822260117, 
>     NA), std.error = c(0.0417633318646855, 0.0512559415739351, 
>     NA), statistic = c(4.90269851299699, 7.26324159859129, 9.6376937050893
>     ), p.value = c(0.0268147618892612, 0.00703801424817208, 0.0080760946996254
>     ), DF = c(NA, NA, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("GMCT_mps ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + ",  "   
> Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category"), num = "n = 236, v = 671", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile"), estimate = c(0.0241593271669994, 
>     -0.0666007869613449, -0.163074252422677, 0.0899012847935602, 
>     0.013943559394045, 0.0129068865425143, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.0400941429467429, 
>     0.0454138676752813, 0.0525343520680203, 0.0594829658990324, 
>     0.0599283957918893, 0.0569649590196029, NA, NA), statistic = c(0.36308457688939, 
>     2.15070944001326, 9.63571690455555, 2.28426542850776, 0.0541354806668636, 
>     0.0513366359485237, 13.6061341648373, 2.67625170039888), 
>         p.value = c(0.546798111190475, 0.142504028765413, 0.00190829707331652, 
>         0.13069200532417, 0.8160174131795, 0.820753538274401, 
>         0.0034933791389206, 0.444278166840459), DF = c(NA, NA, 
>         NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("GMCT_mps ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + ",  "
> Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category"), num = "n = 237, v = 675", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", 
>     "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"
>     ), estimate = c(0.0506591738689037, -0.0368468123937406, 
>     -0.135753001850915, -0.0715855611314002, -0.0903056110998311, 
>     NA, NA), std.error = c(0.0388141649113782, 0.0462112087176506, 
>     0.053281910979695, 0.0407964595310706, 0.0537851643952648, 
>     NA, NA), statistic = c(1.70347479852339, 0.63577755200643, 
>     6.49141385729885, 3.07897325923329, 2.81906098378486, 12.9059982343006, 
>     4.51930360662492), p.value = c(0.191834175517877, 0.42524395559654, 
>     0.0108396733083503, 0.0793105790194146, 0.0931508839484695, 
>     0.00484436297520366, 0.104386825574409), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 
>     NA, NA, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("GMCT_mps ~ AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + ",  "
> Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category"), num = "n = 236, v = 671", 
>     table = structure(list(term = c("AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+", 
>     "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", 
>     "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category"
>     ), estimate = c(0.0770481215334453, -0.0384079604240709, 
>     -0.0330828295158344, -0.0832731659006525, -0.128526526482571, 
>     NA, NA), std.error = c(0.059581121870144, 0.0583721373279554, 
>     0.055587780366665, 0.041329484563662, 0.0510238930591962, 
>     NA, NA), statistic = c(1.67227137942203, 0.432943575872345, 
>     0.354198426884743, 4.05966478138409, 6.34509834630379, 4.34998309557224, 
>     8.19191965566993), p.value = c(0.195954577939597, 0.510548103977062, 
>     0.551746070310006, 0.0439192171347208, 0.0117706083633605, 
>     0.226068166523714, 0.0166397673037754), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, 
>     NA, NA, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>     "tbl", "data.frame"))), list(form = c("GMCT_mps ~ MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile + ",  "   
> MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category + Visit_age + AlcWeek_Category" ),
> num = "n = 236, v = 671", table = structure(list(term =
> c("MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile6.01-15", 
> "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile15.01-53",
> "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile53.01+", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile435.01-861",
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile861.01-1964", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile1964.01+",
> "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category1", 
> "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category2+", "MHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", 
> "AHQ_Heading_Male_Quartile", "MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category" ),
> estimate = c(0.0354548892345223, -0.0457638357151567,
> -0.128823991044636, 
> 0.0846854973713492, 0.00976675574330686, 0.0171278350996467, 
> -0.0649444583952458, -0.093681710240534, NA, NA, NA), std.error = c(0.0393200184837168, 
> 0.046488462709375, 0.0537316384272413, 0.059698051462804, 0.0591007191370332, 
> 0.0562996458832999, 0.0407618682647451, 0.0538668059654375, NA,  NA, NA), statistic = c(0.813064200251411, 0.969068474904697, 
> 5.74821934903142, 2.01232337993008, 0.0273095863691144, 0.0925536647531394, 
> 2.53849338793126, 3.02459459350198, 9.32561500035051, 2.34512015899218, 
> 4.20409892096781), p.value = c(0.367215866960121, 0.324912608474423, 
> 0.0165053786147409, 0.156026213082828, 0.868742392257686, 0.760955460383828, 
> 0.111100752930363, 0.0820108149775128, 0.0252607520289589, 0.503932230891677, 
> 0.122205715642826), DF = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3,  3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" )))))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data or data like it, preferably with `dput()`? That will make it easier for people to help you and to test if their answer actually works for your question.

Comment: I added the dput- it is a bit long unfortunately because I am not sure how to subset nested lists by rows...

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing what you are looking for is `map` and friends from `purrr`.

```
map(1:9, function(i) {
  map(1:7, function(j) {
    result <- tab_male[[i]][[j]]
    cat(result$form, result$num, sep = "\n")
    result_f <- xtable(result$table, digits = c(0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0))
    print(result_f, type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
  })
})
```

or, to be more tidyverse-y,

```
map(tab_male, function(list_i) { # list_i is an element of tab_male
  map(list_i, function(list_j) { # list_j is an element of list_i
    result <- list_j
    cat(result$form, result$num, sep = "\n")
    result_f <- xtable(result$table, digits = c(0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0))
    print(result_f, type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there no function that combines the two maps into one? I was also thinking maybe it's possible to use nest() and create a "list-column" data-frame 7x9, where each element is a list of 3?

Comment: @hlinee The closest thing is `modify_depth(x, 2, fun)`, which is equivalent to `x[] <- map(x, ~ map(., fun))`

Comment: I would think there'd be a way using `tidyr::crossing(i = 1:9, j = 1:7)` and then 
  `purrr::walk2(...)`, but I haven't figured out the syntax right.

Comment: @Phil nice, i agree that's closer. wasn't aware of `modify_depth` before.